# Find Uninstall String from Program Name

Tags: powershell, registry, uninstallation

I'm currently trying to script a way to remove our proxy software from users devices when we need them to be able to use the internet without it. I have the following so far that has worked for programs installed on a Per User basis, but this is a machine install so appears in HKLM rather than HKCU. Can anyone figure out why I would not be getting any output from the following?

```
function Uninstall($DisplayName)
{
Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall' |
% { Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath } |
? { $_.DisplayName -eq $DisplayName } |
% { Write-Output $_.UninstallString }
}

Uninstall "Unified Agent"
```

Comment: Can you please run `Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall' | % { Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath } | Select DisplayName,UninstallString` and verify in the output that 1) there is a DisplayName that would be exactly equal to "Unified Agent" and 2) that it has an UninstallString associated with it?

Comment: As above - not all programs store an uninstall string in that location. Are you sure this one does?

Comment: Ditto to both and did you know that (depending on the OS architecture) there can also be a registry key `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` ?